# Can't manage to echo out row of table using loop without data becoming misaligned on page

Tags: php, mysql

I hope this does not seem like a stupid question - I have been sat for about half an hour trying to tweak the code below to get it to work as desired but no luck so far...

Basically, the code below is intended to form a the basis of a 'regions' page linking to pages for each of these regions. However, at the moment when this is run on the page there is no hyperlink for the first region name pulled from the database, and hence the rest of the link's pages are all out by one row of the data ie:

**Regions**

Borders - no link created

Central - links to courses.php?id=borders

Highlands - links to courses.php?id=central

Western - links to courses.php?id=highlands

And so on

etc etc

I've not had much experience embedding the array row data into links of any sort before so perhaps I just need to tweak the syntax, any pointers would be much appreciated.

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM regions ORDER BY region_name";

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    echo $row['region_name'];

    echo "<a href='courses.php?id=".$row['region_name']."'</a>";

    echo "</br>";

    }
```

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because there is nothing in your `a` tag

Try something like this,

```
echo '<a href="courses.php?id=' . $row['region_name'] . '">' . $row['region_name'] . '</a>";
```

Comment: Thanks Pierre. I've managed to get it to work with a few tweaks to the code you wrote - I think I must be using " and ' very badly as the original code above produced errors in another part of my php further down the page - I have a lot to learn! Thanks again, Chris